# Q: Why not change the time when you run select now()

Tags: python, psycopg2

Why the second call of the rows does not change the displayed date? To correct run select now(), every time I need to recreate the connection?

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 19, 39, 9, 582080)
>>> sql ="""SELECT now();"""
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> rows = cursor.fetchall()
>>> rows
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 19, 39, 31, 397308, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)),)]
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 19, 39, 58, 326446)
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> rows = cursor.fetchall()
>>> rows
[(datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 22, 19, 39, 31, 397308, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)),)]
>>> sql ="""SELECT version();"""
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
>>> rows = cursor.fetchall()
>>> rows
[('PostgreSQL 9.1.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit',)]
```

Comment: It's possible that it's cached the result for the same query, have you looked into the documentation to see if this is the case and whether it can be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of @jonrsharpe's comment, I pulled open psycopg's documentation. From their ["Best Practices" FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html?highlight=cache#best-practices):

> **When should I save and re-use a cursor as opposed to creating a new
>   one as needed?** Cursors are lightweight objects and creating lots of
>   them should not pose any kind of problem. But note that cursors used
>   to fetch result sets will cache the data and use memory in proportion
>   to the result set size. Our suggestion is to almost always create a
>   new cursor and dispose old ones as soon as the data is not required
>   anymore (call `close()` on them.) The only exception are tight loops
>   where one usually use the same cursor for a whole bunch of `INSERT`s or
>   `UPDATE`s.

So, your cursor caches data and you should call [`close()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.close) when you are done with that cursor. Supposedly, these cursors are lightweight and it's not a bad idea to recreate many of them if your application needs this.

Answer (score 0):

Also relevant [advice](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/280) proposing

> A transaction is started at the first query and it is not closed when the cursor is closed. Probably this makes following queries to be executed in the same snapshot. Try putting the connection in autocommit mode or to issuing a connection.rollback() between each query.

UPD: I tried to add `conn.set_session(autocommit=True)` and it helped with unexpected results caching